# How exactly is the electorate badge earned?

Tags: support, badges

I'm looking for a clearer explanation of the Electorate badge as the explanation given doesn't seem clear:

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

This seems redundant, so it's a bit confusing. Looking further and observing the pop-up tag for electorate-badge I see the following:

> A gold badge awarded for doing a lot of voting, and for not forgetting to vote on questions. You must have voted on at least 600 questions and of all your votes ever cast, 25% or more must have been on questions.

I am voting on lots of questions, but don't see the numbers on the badge increasing. What am I missing? Can anyone clarify?

Comment: You have to be in a certain state of mind to invent that description for a badge - and understanding it is much easier if your state of mind is a similar one :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's split the condition you have to meet in order to be awarded the badge into two different conditions:

- You must have voted at least on 600 questions;
- The total number of votes cast on questions (>600 per the previous condition) must constitute at least the 25% of the total numer of votes cast.

So the bare minimum "range" to meet both conditions is the "range" of combinations of votes where you have cast 600 votes on questions and any number of votes from a minimum of 0 to a maximum of 1800 on answers; if you have voted on more than 1800 answers by the time you vote on the 600th question the only way of obtaining the badge is increasing the number of votes cast on questions past 600 and up to a number that constitutes at least the 25% of the total number of votes cast.

Another way to see this is that the number of votes cast on questions must be at least 600 and greater or equal to one third of the number of votes cast on answers.

Examples:

- 1800 votes, 600 on questions and 1200 on answers: badge is awarded (at least 600 votes on questions and 600 is 33,3~% of 1800);
- 1800 votes, 500 on questions and 1300 on answers: badge is not awarded (not enough votes on questions, even if 400 is the 27,7~% of 1800);
- 3600 votes, 600 on questions and 3000 on answers: badge is not awarded (at least 600 votes on questions, but 600 is the 16,6~% of 3600);

Comment: This is a very well written and thought-out answer... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To add to Kos' answer, if you select the Electorate badge as your next tracked badge and then click on it you will get the following dropdown which makes it a lot clearer that you have two conditions you have to have met at the same time. It also tracks both of them separately.

[image: dropdown screen shot]

Comment: Wow +1. Not sure that feature existed when this question was asked, but in either case a great update here, thanks for posting.